# Endless RecyclerView data loading logic is not consistent on all devices

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm loading data from SQLite database in RecyclerView in batch of 25 records per load cycle. I figure out every thing but having problem with logic of calling data loading method in RecyclerView scroll listener.
Problem is list is loading nicely on scroll of recyclerView in emulator but when i tested in physical device, on Lenovo Phab 2 it worked fine but in Mi note 3, list doesn't load consistenly (sometime it loads, sometime not) more records on reaching bottom of scroll.

Below is the code I'm using in RecyclerView scrolle listener

```
private val RecyclerView_ScrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView1: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView1, dx, dy)

        if (dy > 0) {
            if (limit < rowCount_fromDatabase) {
                visibleItemCount = layoutManager_MemberList.childCount
                totalItemCount = layoutManager_MemberList.itemCount
                firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager_MemberList.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

                if (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition >= totalItemCount) {
                    limit += 25
                    load_Data()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try this

```
if (limit < returnedRowCount_fromDatabase) {
    if((dy > 0) && (linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == rowList.size() - 1)){
        limit += 25;
        load_Data();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [class](https://github.com/Ufkoku/AndroidMVPHelper/blob/master/mvp_list/src/main/kotlin/com/ufkoku/mvp/list/util/RecyclerViewOnScrollUpdater.kt), that works with all types of LayoutManagers. It was tested on emulators and real devices.

It has blockers for preventing double loading of next page. When `Listener.onListEndReached()` returns true, it won't be called again, untill `RecyclerViewOnScrollUpdater.loading` will be set to false.

Also you can set `visibleThreshold` and enable/disable page loading via setting `enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

What i use to scroll more is :

```
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
           if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)){
             //Load more data here. It will only trigger when you reach the end of your list and cannot scroll further
           }
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.